# why does std::launch::deferred won't work in the code below? It isn't running any command in the function print_int

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am having hard time getting this std::launch::deferred to work. But it won't go to the method print_int but with std::launch::async I don't have any problem.

```
  void print_int(std::future<int>& fu)
    {
        Debug::out("print_int\n");
        int x = fu.get();
        Debug::out("value inside : %d \n", x);
    
    }
    int main()
    {
        
    
        
    
        std::promise<int> prom;                       // create promise on a stack
        std::future<int> fu = prom.get_future();      // engagement with future
    
        std::future<void> f = std::async(std::launch::deferred,print_int,std::ref(fu));
        //std::future<void> f = std::async(std::launch::async, print_int, std::ref(fu));
    
        prom.set_value(10);
    
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected to happen. Are you aware of how `launch::deferred` works?

Comment: I want the function  print_int to get invoked.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async: *If the deferred flag is set (i.e. (policy & std::launch::deferred) != 0), then async converts f and args... the same way as by std::thread constructor, but does not spawn a new thread of execution. Instead, lazy evaluation is performed: the first call to a non-timed wait function on the std::future that async returned to the caller will cause the copy of f to be invoked (as an rvalue) with the copies of args... (also passed as rvalues) in the current thread (which does not have to be the thread that originally called std::async).

Comment: The result or exception is placed in the shared state associated with the future and only then it is made ready. All further accesses to the same std::future will return the result immediately.*

Comment: Some relevant information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162693/when-to-use-stdlaunchdeferred

Comment: @NathanOliver I am not looking for some theory. I can read those information myself. I did read actually and couldn't figure still. My question is why in the launch::deferred version, the function won't get invoked but in the launch::async version the function it gest invoked.

Comment: _"why in the launch::deferred version, the function won't get invoked"_ - There is a clue in the word _"deferred"_. It's postponed until later. It will get invoked if you `f.get()`/`f.wait()`.

Comment: @passionateProgrammer There is nothing theoretical in my comment.  Did you actually read it?  It says clearly that the thread **wont run** and that it will be lazily evaluated.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you. but i called it i have "fu.get()" inside print_int

Comment: That's the wrong future. Add a call to the deferred one: `f.wait();` or `f.get();` after `prom.set_value(10);`, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/WodWEYand)

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh. i see. thanks. So if that's the wrong future, then how come  std::launch::async invokes the function print_int

Comment: Because `std::launch::async` doesn't defer executing the task. It starts it immediately.